# indefinite integration of polynomial and trignometric functions

Tags: integration

integrate $$\int \frac{(1+ x^2)(2+ x^2)}{(x \cos x + \sin x)^4}dx$$ 
I have tried integration by parts but this x cos x + sin x part is creating problem so i tried substituting it, but unlike x sin x + cos x it is not reducing terms. I think something would be multiplied and divided in the first step, though I am not able to figure out what it is.

Comment: Is this right so?

Comment: yes sir, it is and answer is ((x tan x -1)/(x + tan x)) +(1/3)*(((x tan x -1)^3)/(x + tan x)) + c but i do not know the solution

Answer (score 0):

put x = tan y ,then it will become (sec^4 y)(1+ sec^2 y)dx/((tan y)(cos tan y)+ sin tan y)
then take down sec^4 y in denominator and use sin(A+B) identity, the variable x in the sin(x) in denominator will have differential coefficient in numerator